# Why $rootScope.$new does not let template into the directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, mocha.js, karma-runner

I'm building unit testing using Karma and Mocha. Testing my directives, and using html2js (It converts the htmls to cached strings in $templateCache). 
Interestingly, when using $rootScope.$new() in my test, the template html will not get into the directive . Here's the code:

```
it('should show a thumb name', function() {
  inject(function($compile, $rootScope,$controller) {

  var scope = $rootScope;//.$new() ($new not working. Why?)
  var linkFn = $compile('<thumb></thumb>');
  var element = linkFn(scope);
  scope.$digest(); // <== needed so that $templateCache will bring the html 
                     //     (that html2js put in it)     
  console.log(element.html());// correctly returns thumb's directive templateUrl content
}));
```

...

**However**, if I use scope = $rootScope.$new(), the element.html() will return an empty string

any ideas?

many thanks
Lior

Comment: You need to provide all of your code. Is element defined elsewhere in the test? Is `thumb` a directive?

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs for `$digest` (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope), this will only process watchers etc for the **current** scope and its children.

This suggests to me that when you set `scope = $rootScope` and then `$digest` you will be processing watchers etc on the `$rootScope`, I think this is where promises will be resolved too, releasing your templates. When you do `scope = $rootScope.$new()` and call `$digest` on that, I expect anything that should happen from the `$rootScope` doesn't happen.

So, does this work if you change `scope.$digest()` to `$rootScope.$digest()` or `scope.$apply()`?

Comment: hmm... interesting. you might be right. I'll have to check. thanks!

Comment: Was unsure of `$apply` after writing that answer so I checked the code to make sure it calls digest on the `$rootScope`. - It does, rather than the current.

Comment: I struggled on this for a few hours. This answer confirms some suspicions.